# fixed length file format from datagridview

Tags: c#

I have a client requirment where they need the data in a fixed length format I need to know is there any way to export to text file in fixed lenght format from c#. this was what i wrote but its still confusing with spaces.

```
 string stringSql = " SELECT distinct  " +
                "'" + comboBox6.Text + "' as RecordType" +
               " , left([Claimant Name] +'                              ',30) " +
                " , left([Claimant Address1] +'                             ',30)  " +
                " , left([Claimant Address2] +'                             ',30) as ClaimantAddress2 " +
                " , left([Claimant Address3] +'                             ',30) as ClaimantAddress3 " +
                 " , left([Claimant Address7] +'                             ',29) as ClaimantAddress7 " +
                ", space(59)" +
                " , left(t.t_reference + '                        ' ,23 )  as ClaimantReference " +
                " , left([Claim Number] +'                                     ',7) " +
                " , " + comboBox4.Text + " as CourtCode" +
" ,left(ta_title +'                             ',29) as Title   " +
" ,left(ta_surname +'                             ',29) as Surname   " +
" ,left(ta_othername +'                             ',29 ) as Othername " +
",left(ta_house_number +'                             ',29) as Address1 " +
" ,left(ta_address_1 +'                             ',29)  as  Address2 " +
" ,left(ta_address_2  + '                             ',29) as Address3  " +
",left(ta_address_3 +'                             ',29) as Address4   " +
//",left(ta_address_4 + '                             ',29) as Address5  " +
",left(ta_post_code +'                             ',7) as Address6   " +
 ", space(398)," +
 "RIGHT('00'+CAST(CAST(bat.PCN_Charge* 100.00 AS INT) AS VARCHAR(5)),8) as CLAIMAMT," +
  "RIGHT('0'+CAST(CAST([CFee] * 100 AS INT) AS VARCHAR(5)),5) as CFEE," +
  "RIGHT('00000'+CAST(CAST([Solictors Fees]  AS INT) AS VARCHAR(5)),5)," +
   "RIGHT('000'+CAST(CAST(bat.PCN_Charge + [CFee] AS INT) AS VARCHAR(5)),9) as TotalAMT " +
",left(ISNULL([POC1], '')+'    ',44)" +
",left(ISNULL([POC2], '')+'    ',44)" +
",left(ISNULL([POC3], '')+'    ',44)" +
",Left(ISNULL([t_vrm], '')+'    ',7) " +
",left(ISNULL([POC4], '')+'    ',44)" +
",left(ISNULL([POC5], '')+'    ',44)" +
",left(ISNULL([t_zone_name],'')+'    ',14) " +
",left(ISNULL([POC6], '')+'    ',44)" +
",left(ISNULL([t_date_time_issued],'')+'    ',14) " +
",left(ISNULL([POC7], '')+'    ',44)" +
",left(ISNULL([POC8], '')+'    ',44)" +
",left(ISNULL([POC9], '')+'    ',44)" +
",left(ISNULL([POC10], '')+'    ',44)" +
",left(ISNULL([POC11], '')+'    ',44)" +
",left(ISNULL([POC12], '')+'    ',44)" +
",left(ISNULL([POC13], '')+'    ',44)" +
",left(ISNULL([POC14], '')+'    ',44)" +
",left(ISNULL([POC15], '')+'    ',44)" +
",left(ISNULL([POC16], '')+'    ',44)" +
",left(ISNULL([POC17], '')+'    ',44)" +
",left(ISNULL([POC18], '')+'    ',44)" +
",left(ISNULL([POC19], '')+'    ',44)" +
",left(ISNULL([POC20], '')+'    ',44)" +
",left(ISNULL([POC21], '')+'    ',44)" +
",left(ISNULL([POC22], '')+'    ',44)" +
",left(ISNULL([POC23], '')+'    ',50)" +



" FROM tickets t " +
" LEFT OUTER JOIN  " +
"( " +
"   SELECT ticket_addresses.ta_system_ref, ta_title, ta_othername, ta_surname, ta_house_number, ta_address_1, ta_address_2, " +
"   ta_address_3, ta_address_4, ta_post_code, ta_telephone, ta_organisation " +
"   FROM ticket_addresses " +
"   INNER JOIN " +
"   ( " +
"       SELECT ticket_addresses.ta_system_ref, MAX(ta_address_code) AS ta_address_code " +
"       FROM ticket_addresses " +
"       GROUP BY ta_system_ref " +
"   ) ad " +
"   ON (ticket_addresses.ta_system_ref=ad.ta_system_ref AND ticket_addresses.ta_address_code=ad.ta_address_code) " +
")ta " +
"ON (t.t_number=ta.ta_system_ref) " +
" " +
" Inner JOIN " +
  " ticket_hold_record  b " +
" ON ( t.t_number = b.thr_system_ref) " +
 +

          " and t.t_reference IN {where} ";
  //Generate list of Ticket IDS for SQL Where Clause
            string whereClause = "";
            string[] tempArray = new string[this.txt.Lines.Length];
            tempArray = this.txt.Lines;

            if (this.txt.Lines.Length == 0)
            {
                return;
            }


            for (int counter = 0; counter <= tempArray.Length - 1; counter++)
            {
                if (tempArray[counter].Trim().Length > 0)
                {
                    whereClause = whereClause + "'" + tempArray[counter] + "'" + ", ";
                }
            }
            whereClause = whereClause.TrimEnd(' ', ',');
            whereClause = "(" + whereClause + ")";

            stringSql = stringSql.Replace("{where}", whereClause);

            myDataset = new DataSet("SQL");
            SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection();
           SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand();
            myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            myCommand.CommandText = stringSql;

            myCommand.Connection = myConn;

            SqlDataAdapter myAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand;
            myAdapter.Fill(myDataset);


            this.dataGridView1.DataSource = myDataset.Tables[0];

            for (int counter = 0; counter < myDataset.Tables[0].Columns.Count; counter++)
            {
                this.dataGridView1.Columns[counter].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
            }


            this.dataGridView1.Refresh();

            myConn.Close();
            this.btnGetData.Enabled = true;
            this.btnSave.Enabled = true;
            Application.DoEvents();

        }
```

Comment: Thanks for appreciation  Giammin ...........I know but still working on it for any other classes to export it to fixed file lenght format.

Comment: We don't need your whole application code, give us the exact place where you are stuck and tell us what the problem is.